# Issue with detached binding at initialization for element not in visualtree for WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have had an issue with WPF as of lately. Properties not in the VisualTree have no way of getting the datacontext to work the bindings out. I provide an example.

```
<Path>
  <Path.Data>
     <CombinedGeometry>
       <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
         <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
           <ScaleTransform ScaleY="{Binding WhatScale, Converter={StaticResource DoSomethingAwesome}, FallbackValue=1, TargetNullValue=1}"/>
         </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
       </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
       ...
     </CombinedGeometry>
  </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

I worked it out by adding a dummy reference object and adding that as the source of the binding

```
<FrameworkElement x:Name="DummyElement"/>
...
ScaleY="{Binding DataContext.WhatScale, Converter="{StaticResource DoSomethingAwesome}", Source="{x:Reference DummyElement}}"
```

However: I still get these annoying Information console messages saying

```
BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. 
This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a 
Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.WhatScale
```

The UserControl is rendered from an ItemsControl and the issue I Believe is that the DataContext is null when initialized and directly after is set so the code still works. However, I dont really like that "Information" that I get, I want to understand what happens and how I can avoid it.

Thanks!